# List serialVersionUIDs in serialized data

Tags: java, serialization

I have a file that contains serialized Java classes. I would like to parse this file in order to get a list of the classes in the file and the serialVersionUID of each class.

Is there a tool anyone can recommend to do this, or perhaps someone could offer some pointers on where I should start to accomplish this myself?

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not all classes (even in the JDK) obey the serialisation spec. In particular `readObject` does not always call `defaultReadObject` or `readFields`, with the equivalent mistake in `writeObject`.

You can detect which classes are being used whilst deserialising. `ObjectInputStream` uses `resolveClass` and `resolveProxyClass` to map class descriptors to actual `Class`es (some subclasses you different rules for class loader lookup).

Comment: Thanks, I have subclasssed my ObjectInputStream and logged the requests to the two methods you identify. That has given me enough information to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's already such a tool (if you have access to the classes themselves, the [serialver](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/serialver.html) tool can tell you the ID), but if you need to roll your own,
Sun's [serialzation spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) should contain all the information you need - specifically, the [grammar of the stream format](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258).